# MVC using .netCharting and ABCpdf

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, pdf, charts

**Quick Question:** Is it possible to use .netCharting with MVC by streaming data from a database (using Entity Framework) and generating a PDF (using ABCpdf) by an output stream of the generated chart images/bit-maps? I want to generate the charts on server-side, so I don't think having an HTML page render the charts would be correct.

**Interaction**: The user should be be able to submit their data from a form, have it stream to the database, and then when an admin logs in, they can view a list of users, and be able to
click a button, which generates the updated chart PDF of the specific user from the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where I work we use .netCharting and ABCpdf to produce a lot of documents, generally financial documents with embedded charts, so yes, it is certainly possible. We always use html to generate the pages and this is all done on the server side.

Comment: I understand that the charts can be created via entity framework object parameters placed in the properties of the chart, but could you elaborate on the process of going about taking the generated charts and streaming them into a PDF? Let's say this is all done on server-side when admin fires event button click.

Comment: well for a brief overview, we have a web service which takes in data in a querystring, feeds it into .netCharting and returns and image. Then the code which generates the view add <img> tags with urls that point at the required images. abcPDF then embeds these images into the PDF. There are lots of ways of doing this, you have all the building blocks, I ithnk you should try to implement it bit by bit, and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Jonny. Since using MVC, we're going to go with the approach where the controller passed data from the model to a .netCharting class, then stream this as bits using ABCpdf to render the final view.